# VBA _ Excel Range comments to array

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with an excel file which contains the below values with some cell comments.
[image]

The below VB code is for copy the values and comments to an array.

```
Sub commentToArray()
 arrayValues = Range("A1:A6").Value
 arrayComments = Range("A1:A6").Comment.Text
End Sub
```

The values array is working fine, but the comments array populating an error message.

[image]

Could you please help me to sort this out.

Thanks,
Aneesh

Comment: I doubt `Range.Comment.Text` would work on multiple cells at one go.

Comment: @bulbus is right. You cannot write all comments into an array like this. The reason is that the collection of all comments on a sheet is `ActiveSheet.Comments` and not ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A5").Comments. This is due to the fact that every member in a collection can be addressed. But if a cell does not contain a comment. In short: the collection `ActiveSheet.Cells` will always be `ActiveSheet.Rows.Count` multiplied by `ActiveSheet.Columns.Count` = 17,179,869,184 cells for an Excel 2007 (or higher) sheet. The collection of `ActiveSheet.Comments` is only as big as there are comments on the sheet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Speed Up Working With Comments in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31234053/speed-up-working-with-comments-in-excel-vba) More specifically, the following answer explains better what I was trying to get to in the above comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31235424/1153513

Comment: @Aneesh you posted _"Thanks, Aneesh"_ but the way of give the thanks in  StackOverflow is **Upvoting** in the answer that is useful for you and **Clicking in the check sign**.    You have the bad habit of to post your questions but don't to acknowledge properly the help of the others users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code have two errors:

1. You can't use *Comment.Text* method for a range of multiple cells.
2. You cant' use the *Comment.Text* on a cell that doesn't contains a comment.

This can be a solution for you:

```
Sub commentToArray()
    Dim arrayValues As Variant
    Dim ArrayCommnents() As String
    Dim myRange, commentsRange, mycell As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    arrayValues = Range("A1:A6").Value
    Set myRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A6")
    Set commentsRange = myRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments)
    arrayLenght = commentsRange.Count
    ReDim arrayComments(arrayLenght)

    For Each mycell In commentsRange
        i = i + 1
        arrayComments(i) = mycell.Comment.Text
        Debug.Print (arrayComments(i))
    Next mycell
End Sub
```

Explanation:

- I use `myRange` var with the range to evaluate for comments.
  Next, I need to determine wich cells contain a comment, this is the purpose of `commentsRange` var.
- I've used the `.SpcialCells()` method to get only cells with comments.
- Then, I get the lenght of the `commentsRange` with `.Count` property.  I get the number of cells that constain a comment.
- Redimension the array of comments is needed.
- The `For Each` loop is to get cell by cell comments in the range of cells with comments.  An incremental index `i` to run the array and you got it.